# Not getting yodlee fastlink UI in Iframe after generating url

Tags: yodlee

I have generated yodlee fastlink url for adding account but i am not able to open it in iframe.When i hit that generated url in browser directly it will go directly to callback url.

is it required to open url in popup only.

Below is the fastlink url that i am generating for adding account

https://fl.yodlee.com/appscenter/nationalfunding/linkAccount.pfmmasterfl.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&displayMode=desktop&oauth_callback=https://www.google.com&oauth_consumer_key=a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b&oauth_nonce=8625876&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1435736374&oauth_token=80e9ccb1015c4f77af6feb137b64feb6&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=0LSQEMZ9YM45yR8iTpon5S6WuMI=

Comment: If it's going to call back then definitely there is an Oauth error which gets appended to the call back URL, can you share that. If you are not getting then change the call back URL from google.com to some other website like developer.yodlee.com and give it a try. You will get the oauth_error_code parameter in the call back URL. Need that to help you here.

Comment: Hi Shreyans thanks for your quick reply but the problem has been resolved its due to some problem into oauth code.